# Отмена изменений

Tags: c#, winforms

Все крутится на LightInject. Есть 2 формы. Одна (главная) при необходимости вызывает вторую для детального редактирования объекта класса. У меня это делается так:

```
_controller.Run<WorkerEditorPresenter, Worker>(worker);
```

Соответственно во второй форме метод Run реализован так:

```
public override void Run(Worker worker)
{
    _worker = worker;
    View.ViewModel = new WorkerEditorViewModel(_worker, _correctnessChecker);
    View.Show();
}
```

и на второй форме куча textBox-ов (для редактирования) и 2 кнопки :"Сохранить" и "Отменить". Обработчик "Сохранить" такой: `View.Close();`, а вот в "Отменить" я не знаю что написать, чтобы изменения не сохранились (а еще лучше, чтобы главная форма как-то узнала, что ничего предпринимать (у меня изменения в базу пишутся сразу) не нужно. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не сделать, чтобы изменения писались только при нажатии "Сохранить", а при нажатии "Отмена" ничего не делалось? Если нужно сразу обновлять какие-то представления (до нажатия "Сохранить"), то можно попробовать временно переключать представление на другой (временный) источник данных.

Другой вариант, сохранять состояние textBox-ов при открытии окна, и восстанавливать сохраненное состояние при нажатии "Отмены".

Comment: А как это сделать? Та вторая форма уже получила объект и вывела в textBox-ы все данные. Слова new там нет вообще - это я к тому, что нового объекта не создается - то есть редактируется прям старый. Я Вас если правильно понял, то Вы предлагаете создать копию, и в зависимости от действия (сохранить или отменить) вернуть сохраненное или измененное?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вторая форма получает объект с данными, устанавливает все textBox-ы и сохраняет себе текущее состояние. Если пользователь меняет состояние textBox-ов, то данные меняются, но если происходит отмена, то в данные пишется то состояние, что было сохранено вначале. Но я все-таки за то, чтобы сохранять данные при нажатии "Сохранить", а при отмене ничего не делать.

Comment: Да, вторая форма получает. Вот здесь `View.ViewModel = new WorkerEditorViewModel(_worker, _correctnessChecker);` Создается VewModel (у меня MVP с примесью MVVM), где параметр - тот объект, что нам прислали! А все контролы на этот класс завязаны: то есть если в textBox-е что-то поменялось, то это изменение справедливо и для этого объекта. Все-таки создавать копию, да?